# UIPinchGestureRecognizer

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Right guys, seeing as you were so helpful last time with my previous question with regards to using the UIPinchGestureRecognizer, and adding it programmatically. Which of course worked.

My next question is within the same realms...

I have added limitations to my pinch gesture, so that the user can only zoom in and out as much as I have defined within my variables.

But, I am now stuck. I have a navigation bar and item at the top of my view, but when the user zooms in, this is covered by the scaled image.(Until they zoom out) Is there a way to define the nav bar as "always on top"???

Comment: r you using XIB to design your view?

Comment: Yeh but the UIPinchGestureRecognizer is added to my scroll view programmatically

Comment: and what is the frame for scrollview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the function where you declare your pinch gesture and add it to your scrollview, add this code:

```
[scrollview setClipsToBounds:YES];
```

This will ensure that the content of the scroll view doesn't get out of it.

-EDIT- I edited my response to address the problem. I was missing some parts before :)

Comment: It isnt a view that needs to be ontop, its a UINavigationBar, how would you implement this via code?

Comment: The view you're zooming, is it in a subview of another view?

Comment: Yes I have a view with the navigational Bar and Navigational Item,then a Scroll View which has an Image View, the UIPinchGesture has been added to the Scroll View

Comment: Ah, I see. On that scroll view, try setting the clipsToBounds to YES. That should prevent stuff from flowing out of the scrollview's bounds.

Comment: [scroller clipsToBounds:YES];

returns Instance method '-clipToBounds:' not found (return type to 'id')

Comment: [scroller setClipsToBounds:YES];

Comment: Thanks, it is working now, I think, but now my UIPinchGesture has been overridden thus  meaning the user cannot pinch to zoom?

Comment: Ah, that's something you set with the delegate. It's explained here: http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/ipad/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: My mistake, the UIPinchGesture outlet wasnt attached to the ScrollView so that would be the reason why it wasnt zooming, however the zooming is working now aswell as the scroll, but the setClipsToBounds doesnt not seem to be doing anything?

Comment: Where in your code are you setting the setClipsToBounds? I realize that I left some description text that shouldn't be there, you need to set the clipsToBounds when you declare your scrollview, like on viewDidLoad or in Interface Builder (it's a checkbox), not in the pinch gesture selector. I'll correct it :)